# How can I dynamically add a menu from a SP list on a modern UI site using extensions

Tags: spfx-extensions

I would like to build a custom menu in Modern UI site. The menu data should be coming from a SharePoint list.

I have tried using Application Customizer but no luck as yet on how to retrieve the SharePoint list data and build a menu to the top placeholder.